# How can I create a view of database models in ascending order?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model which looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Avg

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def average_rating(self):
        return self.review_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I would like to create a view that would present each entry in ascending/decending order of it's average rating.

I already have other views that do work like:

```
def price_ascend(request):
    courses=Course.objects.order_by('price')
    return render(request, "courses.html", {"courses": courses})
```

However when trying a similar approach with the average rating:

```
def rating_ascend(request):
    courses=Course.objects.order_by('average_rating')
    return render(request, "courses.html", {"courses": courses})
```

I run into this error:
`Cannot resolve keyword 'average_rating' into field. Choices are: description, id, image, name, orderlineitem, price, review`

Why doesn't this work? In my HTML I have:

```
{% for course in courses|dictsortreversed:"average_rating" %}
                {{ course.average_rating | floatformat }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works and shows the average rating of each course.

This is code where the Review class is defined

```
from django.db import models
from courses.models import Course

# Create your models here.
class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

Comment: The `average_rating` is a model method and it will not perform on the DB level. That is, you can't do a `order by` operation without DB field

Comment: The best thing you can do is, find the average using `annotate` method of the queryset